# Kirchhoffs' radiation law

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, wavelength

I have a doubt regarding [Kirchhoff's law of thermal radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_law_of_thermal_radiation). From what I found online Kirchhoff's law says that the monochromatic absorptance equals emittance in thermodynamic equilibrium, in a particular direction. If the surface is diffuse then the direction does not matter.

My doubt is this:

Suppose we have two diffuse surface bodies in an enclosure at thermal equilibrium, then a particular wavelength specific absorptance for body 1 is $ \alpha_{1} $ and emittance is $ \epsilon_{1} $. Similarly for body 2 the same wavelength specific  emittance is $\epsilon_{2} $ and absorptance is $\alpha_{2}$

$ F_{1-2} A_1 = F_{2-1}A_{2}$, by viewfactor reciprocity.
Assume both have equal areas, then
$ F_{1-2} = F_{2-1}$

Since they are both in thermal equilibrium energy emitted will be equal to energy absorbed.

energy emitted from body 1  to body 2 is: $\epsilon_{1} \sigma T^{4} F_{1-2} $

energy absorbed by body 2 is : $\alpha_2\epsilon_{1} \sigma T^{4} F_{1-2} $

Similarly energy emitted by body 2 to body 1 is: $\epsilon_2 \sigma T^{4} F_{2-1} $

Now equating emitted energy and absorbed energy by body 2: $\epsilon_2 \sigma T^{4} F_{2-1}  =\alpha_2\epsilon_{1} \sigma T^{4} F_{1-2} $

$\epsilon_2 =\alpha_2 \epsilon_1 $

At body 1 we have absorbed energy = $\alpha_1\epsilon_2 \sigma T^{4} F_{2-1} $

equating absorbed energy to emitted energy at body 1: $\alpha_1\epsilon_2 \sigma T^{4} F_{2-1} =\epsilon_{1} \sigma T^{4} F_{1-2} $

$\alpha_1 \epsilon_2= \epsilon_1 $ and from previous result

$\epsilon_2 =\alpha_2 \epsilon_1 $

equating both, we get $\alpha_1 \alpha_2 =1 $, only solution is when both are 1, since for one of them being less than one the other goes above 1.

How is this possible?